# TextView Android displays "null" under actual strings

Tags: android, android-layout

Any ideas where the underlying word "null" may be coming from?  This only appears on certain devices, most devices I've tested do not have this underlying word.  Below is a partial screen shot showing the issue with the word "null" in my layout:

[image]

EDITED:  Here is the xml:

```
        <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/day"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="DAY: "
        style="@style/ForecastLayout.Detail.DayTextSizeBold"/>
```

and the code that populates it:

TextView dayTitle_tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.day);

buf = mContext.getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.day).toUpperCase();

```
            dayTitle_tv.setText(buf + ":");
```

I do the same thing for the titles seen at the bottom of the screen image I uploaded:

```
// headings
            // precip
            tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.precip_title);
            tv.setText(mContext.getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.precip).toUpperCase());

            // day
            tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.day_title);
            tv.setText(mContext.getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.day).toUpperCase());

            // night
            tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.night_title);
            tv.setText(mContext.getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.night).toUpperCase());
```

and I do not get the "null" underlying. Hmmm?

Comment: What's the XML for that view?

Comment: I updated my post with XML and code.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed initialize my variable to something other than "null".  I didn't see that another developer had initialized this variable to "null".  I changed this to an empty string and the problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect because you're defining the text directly rather than referencing a resource file (as you should be doing), Android is seeing that there is no resource defined for this field.

It then says "oh, this field has nothing in it" and so assigns a null value to the Spannable that it uses to draw it, but also draws your text.

Try switching to using resource files and see if it helps.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean...Don't I already reference through resources?  mContext.getApplicationContext().getResources...

Comment: You're defining "Day: " in your XML layout file rather than your strings.xml file.  The code you posted is irrelevant, the problem is in your TextView for "Day: ".

Comment: I can completely remove that line in the xml and I still get this display issue.  I can also populate with the string resource and still get the same display issue.

Comment: Why are you defining the layout text in code?  It's already static text laid out in the resource files.  You are likely referencing a non-existent string.  Try ctrl-clicking the R.string.day to see if it actually goes anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access the `android:text` in you xml file use `TextView.getText();`

since you reference a string resource

```
R.string.day
```

it seems the there is no string called day if you want you can add it to your res/values/strings.xml

by adding this

```
<string
        name="day"
        >some value </string>
```

and add it to the text view like this

```
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/day"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="@string/day"
    style="@style/ForecastLayout.Detail.DayTextSizeBold"/>
```

so if you make this call

```
buf = mContext.getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.day).toUpperCase();
```

it won't return null value

Comment: Utilizing the string resource still produces same display issue with "null" underlying.